# Get actual cursor when type is 'auto'

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, mouse-cursor

I'm using this code to get cursor type (using jQuery):

```
$('*').mouseenter(function(){
    var cursor = $(this).css('cursor');
    console.log(cursor);
});
```

But on some elements it prints `auto` (which is the default option and means that the browser determine the cursor type).

I need to be able to know what the browser actually displays in those cases (i.e. `pointer`, `resize`, etc.)

For example: for a link element (tagName=A) it prints 'auto', but displays 'pointer'.

How can I know which cursor type will be eventually displayed on the specific browser? In other words, how can I tell which cursor type the browser will choose?

Is this behavior documented somewhere?

Comment: As you say it's determined by the browser. 'auto' is the css value. If you want it to be different why not give cursor values to you elements in css.

Comment: The default value of cursor type is auto, you can find here https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

Comment: Why not decide the cursor type based on the element. You can just build a table with element types with their default cursor for each browser. I don't think there is any other way.

Answer (score 1):

This is [determined by the user agent (=browser)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#cursor), which uses the platform specific default cursor for the element you are currently hovering.

> **general purpose cursors**
>   ***'auto'***
>   The UA determines the cursor to display based on the current context, specifically: auto behaves as text over text, and default otherwise.

So you cannot possibly tell what the cursor will look like when it is set to auto in the css.

I guessed there should be an overview which html element receives which cursor type so you could just decide based on the element type, but I could not find anything online. Also, there is no guarantee, that a certain browser will actually use that cursor, since `auto` gives them free reign, which cursor type to use.

The only option to have control over this is to explicitely set the cursor to a specific type. (Also, I would be interested in a detailed use case where you need this).

Comment: What I'm interested at is how the browser decides. I'm writing a third-party util class, and does not want to alter the site's CSS.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. The browser decides what to do and does not disclose it's decision.

Comment: @OmriSh That's what I've found, too. There are elements that have multiple different cursors depending on their content, for example `text` over text and `default` over empty areas. You could look at the element and make a guess, and if in doubt, assume `default`. That's what I'll do now.

Answer (score 0):

The browser determines your `cursor` as `auto` because it was never specified by your code. If you want to get the current `cursor` you would have to set it in your CSS or HTML explicitly for every element you would like to examine.

```
a {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

After specifying it, `.css('cursor')` will return its type.

Comment: This was just an example, I need to know that for any tag.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean - if you want to get it on **any** tag, you would need to specify it on **any** tag. else, the browser will use the default, which is `auto`.

Comment: What you did in your answer is telling the browser what to do explicitly, this is not what I want.

Comment: @KobyDouek, the OP doesn't want to _set_ the cursor type, they want to _detect_ what was the computed type.